# Prevent Race Condition in Efficient Consumer Producer model

Tags: c#, multithreading, race-condition

What I am trying to achieve is to have a consumer producer method. There can be many producers but only one consumer. There cannot be a dedicated consumer because of scalability, so the idea is to have the producer start the consuming process if there is data to be consumed and there is currently no active consumer.

```
 1. Many threads can be producing messages. (Asynchronous)
 2. Only one thread can be consuming messages. (Synchronous)
 3. We should only have a consumer in process if there is data to be consumed 
 4. A continuous consumer that waits for data would not be efficient if we add many of these classes.
```

In my example I have a set of methods that send data. Multiple threads can write data `Write()` but only one of those threads will loop and Send data `SendNewData()`. The reason that only one loop can write data is because the order of data must be synchronous, and with a `AsyncWrite()` out of our control we can only guarantee order by running one `AyncWrite()` at a time.

The problem that I have is that if a thread gets called to `Write()` produce, it will queue the data and check the `Interlocked.CompareExchance` to see if there is a consumer. If it sees that another thread is in the loop already consuming, it will assume that this consumer will send the data. This is a problem if that looping thread consumer is at "Race Point A" since this consumer has already checked that there is no more messages to send and is about to shut down the consuming process.

Is there a way to prevent this race condition without locking a large part of the code. The real scenario has many queues and is a bit more complex than this.

In the real code `List<INetworkSerializable>` is actually a byte[] BufferPool. I used List for the example to make this block easier to read.

With 1000s of these classes being active at once, I cannot afford to have the SendNewData looping continuously with a dedicated thread. The looping thread should only be active if there is data to send.

```
public void Write(INetworkSerializable messageToSend)
{
   Queue.Enqueue(messageToSend);

   // Check if there are any current consumers. If not then we should instigate the consuming.
   if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref RunningWrites, 1, 0) == 0)
   { //We are now the thread that consumes and sends data
     SendNewData();
   }
}

//Only one thread should be looping here to keep consuming and sending data synchronously.
private void SendNewData()
{
    INetworkSerializable dataToSend;
    List<INetworkSerializable> dataToSendList = new List<INetworkSerializable>();

    while (true)
    {
        if (!Queue.TryDequeue(out dataToSend))
        {
           //Race Point A
           if (dataToSendList.IsEmpty)
           {
              //All data is sent, return so that another thread can take responsibility.
              Interlocked.Decrement(ref RunningWrites);
              return;
           }

           //We have data in the list to send but nothing more to consume so lets send the data that we do have.             
           break;
        }

        dataToSendList.Add(dataToSend);
    }

    //Async callback is WriteAsyncCallback()
    WriteAsync(dataToSendList);
}

//Callback after WriteAsync() has sent the data.
private void WriteAsyncCallback()
{
    //Data was written to sockets, now lets loop back for more data
    SendNewData();
}
```

Comment: Not 100% sure what your requirements are, but would it possibly make more sense to have a thread that is dedicated to monitoring the queue and sending messages, that is not to do with the 'writes' at all?  This would remove some of this complexity for you.

Comment: Can you explain the meaning of dataBufferOffset variable. Cos from source code you've provided it's not clear.

Comment: Paddy, thank you for your suggestion but that is exactly what I am trying to prevent with this code. The point is that if I have 1000s of these classes running, I would only like to loop the send methods if there is data to be sent. I have modified the post to include this restriction.

Comment: Woodman, you are right that it was not clear at all. I have changed this to a List to show what it is doing. It was originally writing to a byte[] buffer pool.

Comment: I'm still confused by the requirement. If there already 1000's of producers, why would one more consumer thread matter?  'A continuous consumer that waits for data would not be efficient if we add many of these classes' - why not?  I'm sorry, I don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The race condition can be prevented by adding the following and double checking the Queue after we have declared that we are no longer the consumer.

```
if (dataToSend.IsEmpty)
{
     //Declare that we are no longer the consumer.
     Interlocked.Decrement(ref RunningWrites);

     //Double check the queue to prevent race condition A
     if (Queue.IsEmpty)
         return;
     else
     {   //Race condition A occurred. There is data again.

         //Let's try to become a consumer.
         if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref RunningWrites, 1, 0) == 0)
               continue;

         //Another thread has nominated itself as the consumer. Our job is done.
         return;
     }                                    
}

break;
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you would be better off with the producer-consumer pattern that is easily implemented with the [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx):

```
var toSend = new BlockingCollection<something>();

// producers
toSend.Add(something);

// when all producers are done
toSend.CompleteAdding();


// consumer -- this won't end until CompleteAdding is called
foreach(var item in toSend.GetConsumingEnumerable())
   Send(item);
```

To address the comment of knowing when to call CompleteAdding, I would launch the 1000s of producers as tasks, wait for all those tasks to complete (Task.WaitAll), and then call CompleteAdding.  There are good overloads taking in CancellationTokens that would give you better control, if needed.

Also, TPL is pretty good about scheduling off blocked threads.

More complete code:

```
var toSend = new BlockingCollection<int>();            
Parallel.Invoke(() => Produce(toSend), () => Consume(toSend));

...

private static void Consume(BlockingCollection<int> toSend)
{
    foreach (var value in toSend.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sending {0}", value);
    }
}

private static void Produce(BlockingCollection<int> toSend)
{
    Action<int> generateToSend = toSend.Add;

    var producers = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000)
                              .Select(n => new Task(value => generateToSend((int) value), n))
                              .ToArray();

    foreach(var p in producers)
    {
        p.Start();
    }

    Task.WaitAll(producers);
    toSend.CompleteAdding();
}
```

Comment: There's also the [TPL DataFlow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603.aspx) which might be a good fit here. Just a thought.

Comment: Austin, Thanks for your suggestion. Would this require a thread just to perform consuming? That is what I am trying to avoid with this method since 1000s of these classes must be run simultaneously. I have made some edits to the original post to add some clarity.

Comment: @JamesHarmon:  Yes it would.  _A continuous consumer that waits for data would not be efficient if we add many of these classes_ -- this makes no sense.

Comment: @JamesHarmon:  The overhead and complexity added by not having the separate thread seems like it would negate any inefficiencies (if any) caused by the separate thread.

Comment: @AustinSalonen: I do not see how this fits the original model. Since many producers continually produce asynchronously, there would never be a time that everyone is finished as there may be more data in the future. so who and when would call CompleteAdding()? Secondly we have an iteration on this collection that is spinning continuously trying to consume data that for the vast majority of time is probably not there, would running 1000s of these be efficient?

Comment: There is a "trick" in BlockingCollection, so there will be no forever spinning threads, that dedicated thread will just wait until new data is added to collection. And you can call CompleteAdding() just before shutting down application, for example.

Comment: Thank you again Woodman and Austin. Although I do not think that it fits this situation in that it will cause many blocked threads, it is a great tool to remember for future use.

Comment: @JamesHarmon:  _Although I do not think that it fits this situation in that it will cause many blocked threads_ -- why do you think this is the case?  The only way this is true is if it's also the case in the original implementation.

Comment: @JamesHarmon: FWIW, I've used this model in a similar apps (thousands of network connections, single consumer) and the consumer caused no issues.  The real work was throttling the producers to maximize the network usage.

Answer (score 1):

Check this variant. There are some descriptive comments in code.
Also notice that `WriteAsyncCallback` now don't call `SendNewData` method anymore

```cs
private int _pendingMessages;

    private int _consuming;

    public void Write(INetworkSerializable messageToSend)
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref _pendingMessages);
        Queue.Enqueue(messageToSend);

        // Check if there is anyone consuming messages
        // if not, we will have to become a consumer and process our own message, 
        // and any other further messages until we have cleaned the queue
        if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _consuming, 1, 0) == 0)
        {
            // We are now the thread that consumes and sends data
            SendNewData();
        }
    }

    // Only one thread should be looping here to keep consuming and sending data synchronously.
    private void SendNewData()
    {
        INetworkSerializable dataToSend;
        var dataToSendList = new List<INetworkSerializable>();
        int messagesLeft;

        do
        {
            if (!Queue.TryDequeue(out dataToSend))
            {
                // there is one possibility that we get here while _pendingMessages != 0:
                // some other thread had just increased _pendingMessages from 0 to 1, but haven't put a message to queue.
                if (dataToSendList.Count == 0)
                {
                    if (_pendingMessages == 0)
                    {
                        _consuming = 0;
                        // and if we have no data this mean that we are safe to exit from current thread.
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // We have data in the list to send but nothing more to consume so lets send the data that we do have.             
                    break;
                }
            }

            dataToSendList.Add(dataToSend);
            messagesLeft = Interlocked.Decrement(ref _pendingMessages);
        }
        while (messagesLeft > 0);

        // Async callback is WriteAsyncCallback()
        WriteAsync(dataToSendList);
    }

    private void WriteAsync(List<INetworkSerializable> dataToSendList)
    {
        // some code
    }

    // Callback after WriteAsync() has sent the data.
    private void WriteAsyncCallback()
    {
        // ...
        SendNewData();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort! It is an interesting solution. Unfortunately the BCL implementation of sockets SendAsync States that sending data does not guarantee that all bytes were buffered. So the sendasycncallback must check which bytes were not buffered and attempt to buffer those bytes. This means that having more then one consumer can lead to packets being fragmented and blended within other packets.

Comment: So you are saying that in WriteAsyncCallback() you are making some additional checks and in some circumstances you call SendNewData(), right?

Comment: Exactly, if not all data is sent then we loop back to WriteAsync from the callback. This is done to send the remaining unsent bytes

Comment: So requirements are even more strict - consuming should be stopped completely until WriteAsyncCallback method gets called, correct?

Comment: Correct, that is why at most we can have one consuming thread. It is also why in the original example, SendNewData() does not loop. The full loop is when we call SendNewData() from the callback.

Comment: Please check corrected code, I've added check to assure that only one thread consuming messages at any given moment. I'm not 100% sure in it's correctness it's quite late here at the moment. I'll check my code tomorrow with fresh eye, probably we need to add some locks in code to make it thread-safe